# How to regenerate url path dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php

I created simple project in PHP and seperated my works to different folders.

My folder structure:

```
system
├── dashboard
│   ├── account
│   │   └── logout.php
│   ├── employees
│   │   └── addemployee.php
│   └── layout
        └── sidebar.php
```

In my sidebar.php I have listed items with links. And I load this sidebar.php in every required PHP pages. But the problem is that the path of links changes on the pages where sidebar.php is loaded.

**Example:**

In the addemployee.php where sidebar.php and its links are loaded:

```
<a href="account/logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Normally the path of the Logout should be like this:

*`http://localhost/system/dashboard/account/logout.php`*

But its not so. This path changes in the addemployee.php page as follows:

*`http://localhost/system/dashboard/employees/account/logout.php`*

How can I prevent this from happening?
Thank you

Comment: Use full path: "/system/dashboard/account/logout.php". Starting with / means root folder relative to site. ./ means current folder. ../ means parent folder.

Comment: thank you @armagedescu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the absolute path:

```
<a href="/system/dashboard/account/logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Thanky for your answer. Its super easy and fast method. I dont know why people are using this for defining url location `../`